# cannot stub ReactiveMongoRepository using Mockito.when

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux

I'm new to reactive programming. I want to write some test cases for a reactive mongo repository. I tried to stub some query methods and use step-verifier to check the response, but my test gets fail .

**ItemReactiveRepository.java**

```
public interface ItemReactiveRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Item, String> {
Mono<Item> findByDescription(String description);
}
```

**Item.java**

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Item {

@Id
private String id;
private String description;
private Double price;
}
```

**ItemReactiveRepositoryTest.java**

```
@DataMongoTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ItemReactiveRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private ItemReactiveRepository itemReactiveRepository;


@Test
public void findById() {

    Item itemForTest = new Item("ABC", "Samsung TV", 405.0);

    Mockito.when(itemReactiveRepository.findById("ABC")).thenReturn(Mono.just(itemForTest));

    StepVerifier.create(itemReactiveRepository.findById("ABC"))
            .expectSubscription()
            .expectNextMatches(item -> item.getPrice() == 405.0)
            .verifyComplete();
 }
}
```

**Error I receive when running test**

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> For example:
> when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

> Also, this error might show up because:
>
> 1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
>    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
>    Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
> 2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Are there any limitations to use stubbing when test reactive streams? Or any other standard mechanism to test above scenarios?

Comment: No there is no limitations, you are just writing the code wrong. When `@DataMongoTest` is used, your application will start with an in memory mongo, so you actually dont need to mock anything. If you want to mock your repository, you dont need that annotation, and you need to actually provide a Mock by using `@MockBean`. If you want to test things i recommend you just look up in the official documentation how to test things before you ask here. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mongo-test

Comment: and mockbean https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thank you very much for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@Autowired` you have to prepare mock for Repository from `import org.mockito.Mock;`

```java
@Mock
ItemReactiveRepository itemReactiveRepository;
```

As @Thomas has mentioned, you are not mocking instead using the actual MongoDB using `DataMongoTest` instead you have to get rid of this and just mock the methods and test your service layer. `Autowired` is expecting all default configuration and a bean which is prepared by the container for you to use which is not the case, you have to mock and use.

Answer (score 0):

```
ItemReactiveRepository itemReactiveRepository=org.mockito.Mockito.mock(ItemReactiveRepository.class);
```

This worked for me.